# Connect Ceiling Light Fixture to Recessed Lighting Socket

Tags: recessed-lighting

[image]Is it possible to use the existing recessed lighting socket and black/white wires connected to the socket to connect a light fixture rather than removing the entire recessed canister and box and pulling the wires?  I would like a light fixture where the recessed light is, but would prefer not to destroy the ceiling to get to the wiring.

Comment: Never mind, it seems that they sell converters.

Comment: that would make a great answer to your own question if you wrote it up in more detail

Comment: Here's is a site you can start at. https://thecanconverter.com/